# mixed c/asm project (x64) yields one "unresolved external" (fixed all the others!)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, assembly, x86-64

I have a Visual Studio project that I want to build in both 32 and 64 bit variants. It is 99% written in C/C++, but has one function written in assembler. In 32 bit, I have the asm code in a cpp file as follows:

```
#ifndef X64
__declspec( naked ) void ERR ( )
{
    SeqNum = 0;
    SeqTimeStamp++;
    __asm
    {
        mov EAX, MinusTwo
        mov EBP, SaveBP
        sub EBP, 4
        mov ESP, EBP
        pop EBP
        ret 8
    }
}
#endif
```

The referenced globals are defined at the top of the same file as follows:

```
extern "C"
{
DWORD           SeqTimeStamp, SeqNum;
void            *SaveBP;
}
```

This compiles and builds fine. (And works, too! :-) )

For the 64-bit build, with no inline asm support, the same basic algorithm is coded in a .ASM file. I have Visual Studio (2010) building this file just fine, and including it in the call to link. That code looks like this:

```
EXTERN SaveBP:PTR
EXTERN SeqNum:DWORD
EXTERN SeqTimeStamp:DWORD
.CODE
ERR PROC PUBLIC FRAME
PUSH RBP
MOV RBP, RSP
.ENDPROLOG
MOV SeqNum, 0
MOV EAX, SeqTimeStamp
INC EAX
MOV SeqTimeStamp, EAX
MOV RAX, 0FFFFFFFEh
MOV RBP, SaveBP
LEA RSP,[RBP+0]
POP RBP
RET 0
ERR ENDP
END
```

I get a single undefined external in this build:
ERR.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SaveBP referenced in function ERR

I've tried a number of different ways of declaring and referencing SaveBP, but I haven't found a winning combination. Has anyone else run into a similar situation, or might know how to solve it?

Comment: Any special reason to use assembly and not intrinsic functions? Will save you writing the code twice. Might even work faster as the optimizer has a chance to work (e.g. inline this function).

Comment: Hmm -- ignorance? I do use the intrinsic _AddressOfReturnAddress to get my value of SaveBP elsewhere, but I'm not aware of an intrinsic to allow me to "assert" a new return address. The intent here, if it's not obvious, is to be able to return from whence I came, even if I'm 6 function calls deep. If there's an appropriate intrinsic, I'd love to use it! But I'm not interested in re-writing the code to use a different model (like throw/catch).

Comment: Here's a snippet from the ASM file emitted for the cpp file where those globals are defined. Seems like the compiler isn't paying attention to the extern "C" for pointers??
PUBLIC SeqTimeStamp
PUBLIC SeqNum
PUBLIC ?SaveBP@@3PEAXEA    ; SaveBP
_BSS SEGMENT
SeqTimeStamp DD 01H DUP (?)
SeqNum DD 01H DUP (?)
?SaveBP@@3PEAXEA DQ 01H DUP (?)    ; SaveBP

Comment: Tried redefining SaveBP as type INT_PTR but name still mangled...

Comment: Hmm. Trivial test app doesn't show this problem. Must keep digging.

Comment: I guess this was occurring because the source file (X.cpp) first included a header (X.h) which had declared this variable as: extern void    *SaveBP;
Adding the "C" here, too, fixed the problem.